# Scale map to fit points IN FACET_WRAP

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some map data that is divided into groups and want to draw a facet_wrap

This is the code that I have so far:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

test_points =data.frame( map = c(rep("AAA", 5),rep("BBB", 5),rep("CCC", 5),rep("DDD", 5)),
                          LAT = c(runif(5, -90, -45), runif(5, -45, 0), runif(5, 0, 45), runif(5, 45, 90)),
                      LON = c(runif(5, -180, -90), runif(5, -90,0), runif(5, 0, 90), runif(5, 90, 180)))

map_lim = test_points %>%
            group_by(map) %>% 
            summarise(y_min = floor(min(LAT)),
                      y_max = ceiling(max(LAT)),
                      x_min = floor(min(LON)),
                      x_max = ceiling(max(LON)))

worldmap = map_data("world")

ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = worldmap,
                 aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
    geom_point(data = test_points,
               aes(x = LON, y = LAT, group= map, colour = map)) +
    #coord_cartesian(
    #        ylim=c(map_lim[ map_lim$map==map, 2], map_lim[ map_lim$map==map, 3]),
    #        xlim=c(map_lim[ map_lim$map==map, 4], map_lim[ map_lim$map==map, 5])
    #) +
    coord_cartesian(
            ylim=c(map_lim$y_min, map_lim$y_max),
            xlim=c(map_lim$x_min, map_lim$x_max)
    ) +
    facet_wrap(~ map, scales = "free")
```

You can see that I have tried two methods of limiting the coordinates.. neither work.

What I get is the whole world ... with five points on each.

Is it possible scale each of the maps independently?

Comment: try using geom_map rather than geom_polygon

Comment: I tried this and it didn't seem to work.  I also tried joining the 4 limit parameters back into the test_points DF.  This didn't work either.

I think I will have to create 4 separate maps then bring them together on the same page.

Comment: what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`geom_map` is the better than `geom_polygon` as it automatically truncates to the region needed by the points etc.

```
worldmap <- map_data("world")

ggplot() +
  geom_map(data = worldmap, map = worldmap, mapping = aes(map_id = region)) +
  geom_point(data = test_points,
             aes(x = LON, y = LAT, group= map, colour = map)) +
  coord_equal() +
  facet_wrap(~ map, scales = "free")
```

The only problem is that `scales = "free"` doesn't play with non-Cartesian coords, so you cannot use `coord_map` or a specific cartographic projection. `coord_fixed` might be better if your latitudes are similar.

Comment: I don't know what I was doing wrong ... possibly in the mapping = aes(map_id = region)

That give me exactly what I want!